# Download de arquivo jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Eu tenho uma função de click em jQuery e queria que eu clicar no botão ele faça o download de um arquivo PDF, como eu faço essa função?

```js
  $('#download').click(function() {
  
  //seria aqui a função
  
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="download"> Download PDF </button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: [`<a href='meu-arquivo.pdf' download>Baixar Arquivo</a>`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: Vale observar que por questões lógicas e até de segurança, quem decide o download é o desenvolvedor do site. Você pode disponibilizar download de `qualquer arquivo` desde que esteja publicado no seu domínio. Se fizer `<a href='meu-arquivo.PHP' download>Download</a>` vai disponibilizar para baixar.